# Is it possible to set return type of a function to be the return type of it's callback function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following function

```
export const tryAsyncAwait = async (fn: () => any) => {
  try {
    const data = await fn();
    return [data, null];
  } catch (error) {
    return [null, error];
  }
};
```

If I pass in this function...

```
const getNum = (x: number) => x * 2
```

I would like typescript to infer the return type of **tryAsyncAwait** to be return: [number, null]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the desired behavior the function should have the following type signature:

```
export const tryAsyncAwait = async <F extends () => any>(
    fn: F
): Promise<[ReturnType<F>, null]> => {
    try {
        const data = await fn();
        return [data, null];
    } catch (error) {
        return [null, error];
    }
};
```

But since there is an alternate `return` in the `catch` block, the type must be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the resolved and rejected value in order to be correct.

```
export const tryAsyncAwait = async <F extends () => any>(
    fn: F
): Promise<[ReturnType<F>, null] | [null, unknown]> => {
    try {
        const data = await fn();
        return [data, null];
    } catch (error) {
        return [null, error];
    }
};
```

Also, keep in mind the return type must be wrapped in a `Promise` as `async` is used in the function definition. As the call to `fn` is awaited, this assumes other `async` functions can be passed as a callback. The type signature `() => any` is wide enough to cover these cases.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. There are quite a few holes in my knowledge of TS.